How can I store list of t1waybt ANOVAs (WRS2 package) into a data frame (R)
I have computed 12 ANOVAs using WRS2 package, with the t1waybt function. I would like to be able to put all of these results into a data frame so I can view/print them all.
I have tried the following code:
anova_role_stss_table <- list(anova_role_stss_Int, anova_role_stss_Av, anova_role_stss_Ar)

anova_role_stss_tidy <- lapply(anova_role_stss_table, tidy)

Error: No tidy method for objects of class t1waybt
This is my code using 3 of those tests. I'd like to be able to store them in a df, and print them.
Much appreciated in advance.

The help page help("t1waybt") says that the object returned by t1waybt is a list with 6 members. So the "t1waybt" objects list is piped to the extractor [ and the 6th element is removed from the t1waybt objects. Then the list members are rbinded.
library(WRS2)

anova_role_stss_Int <- t1waybt(libido ~ dose, data = viagra)
#> Warning in t1waybt(libido ~ dose, data = viagra): Some bootstrap estimates of
#> the test statistic could not be computed.
anova_role_stss_Av <- t1waybt(libido ~ dose, data = viagra)
#> Warning in t1waybt(libido ~ dose, data = viagra): Some bootstrap estimates of
#> the test statistic could not be computed.

anova_role_stss_table <- list(anova_role_stss_Int, anova_role_stss_Av)

anova_role_stss_table |>
  lapply(`[`, -6L) |>
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, args = _)
#>   test    p.value Var.Explained Effect.Size nboot.eff
#> 1    3 0.08311688     0.6232175   0.7894413       385
#> 2    3 0.07989691     0.6232175   0.7894413       388

Created on 2024-07-13 with reprex v2.1.0

do.call(what=rbind.data.frame) is less strange to read immo.

@Friede Yes, you are right. I had never thought of that, always learning, thanks.
